# bash script creating string from number with plus sign

Tags: bash, escape-characters

In a bash script, I stumbled over a simple looking problem of creating an expression from a parameter given as number and adding a plus `+` sign in front of it:

```
YEA= expr $2 \* 365
echo ${YEA}
pl="+"
echo "${pl}${YEA}"
```

which I expect to concatenate to a string, so for example `$2=10` should output:

```
3650
+3650
```

While it does work fine at the command line, in the script it only outputs

```
3650
+
```

I tried also using `printf` and `awk`, which do kind of the same thing.
So I figured my problem is with bash.

Can someone please explain why this happens?

Comment: As shown, it does not work at the command line either. Instead of invoking `expr`, you might consider the ability of Bash to calculate with integers, and the printf option to assign to variables. `printf -v Days '%+d' $(( $2 * 365 ))`

Comment: Try running your script through [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) and examine the errors.

Comment: what with the space, and the somewhat dated `expr`, I wonder if this is a copy-paste error from some example with a backtick command substitution there. E.g. `YEA=\`expr ...\``. Better not use either, backticks or `expr`.

Answer (score 3):

The space after the assignment operator shouldn't be there.

```
YEA= expr $2 \* 365
#   ~
```

With the space, it runs the `expr` with the `$YEA` environment variable explicitly set to the empty string. `expr` doesn't care about the environment variable, but does the calculation and outputs the result. The variable in the context of the shell doesn't change.

To assign the output of a command to a variable, use command substitution:

```
YEA=$(expr $2 \* 365)
```

or use arithmetic evaluation without `expr`:

```
(( YEA = $2 * 365 ))
```

Comment: it actually does output the $YEA variable correct. The problem occurs with the +

Comment: @EchoUni no, it doesn't. The `3650` you see comes from `expr` being outputted to your screen, instead of being saved in `YEA`. To verify, add an `echo hi` between your `YEA= expr $ \* 365` and your `echo ${YEA}`